# How do you add an XsltListViewWebPart to a Client Web Part (App Part) page?

Tags: listview, xslt, sharepoint-2013

I've had a lot of trouble trying to create a Client Web Part that displays a Custom List View, using the XsltListViewWebPart I managed to create a page that displays the way I want it to in the App Part. 
I used a copy of Default.aspx with a modified master page to do this but I can't seem to get the controls to work. 
The problems I'm faced with are that the New Item form tries to open in the iFrame (no success as it is not Framable), I don't know how to add ribbon controls to the Host Web to allow the user to modify the List Data, 
and while I can see the list of Custom Views I have created I am not able to select any of them.

So what I really want to know is;

**-Does anyone know of an easier way to add a list instance to a Client Web Part page?**

**-How do I get the ribbon controls for the list from the App Web and display them in the Ribbon on the Host Web?**

**-How do I get the 'new item' control to open the NewForm.aspx page in the Host Web and not the App Web?**

I am an Apprentice Software Engineer and I only just started learning SharePoint so it's possible that this is really easy but I have absolutely no idea where to go from here as I couldn't find information on this anywhere, please help.